# how to generate token for agora RTC for live stream and join channel

Tags: agora.io

i'm building live streaming application *i wanna to use Agora RTC for live streaming. how to generate token from PHP server.*

currently i'm generating tokens from this repository but token not working and streaming not initiating.

https://github.com/AgoraIO/Tools/tree/master/DynamicKey/AgoraDynamicKey/php/sample

i tried all tokens but noting happens

Answer (score 0):

This document explains how to generate a token using the Agora token generator. You can take a look and see if you have entered the correct information in the token generator such as appID and channel name. Also you might need to check if you have put correct expiration time for your token. The expiration time should be in Unix timestamp.

https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/token_server?platform=Android#reference

Comment: Thanks for response.
token is generated successfully. but it is not working with mobile app. in mobile app it is showing nothing and not streaming. i want to generate correct token